# .hash in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am encountering a function (?) that I do not fully understand in Rails and ActiveRecord.

I am building a basic website where the user (created with `devise`) can upload a `document` (the fields are: `title` and the `attachment`)
Therefore, when the users goes to `www.website.com/documents/new` he is present with a simple_form that asks him to write a title and attache a PDF.
Once confirmed, the document is saved in the database and linked to the user. Everything works fine.

My question is the following: when I run `rails console` and run `Document.last.hash` (or for any other stored document), I get back a numeric field back such as: `3130256425345013276`

Can someone explain me what it is?
Is it a hash function (like `SHA-256 algorithm`) to secure the encryption in the database?
If yes, among all the hash functions, which is the one ActiveRecord is using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it a hash function to secure the encryption in the database?

It *is* a hash function, but has nothing to do with encryption. It's used when you use objects as keys in [hashes](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html).

Comment: Thanks! So I cannot use the `3130256425345013276 ` as a strong encryption value that prevents malicious people to understand what my `document` contains?